# Name of a painting in Wall Street (1987)

Tags: props, wall-street

I am looking for a name of the painting or artist featured in Bud's apartment. I tried to google the artists in credits but no luck.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've added a second angle (slightly different lighting) in case anyone wants to try an image search.

Comment: I might know, but is there any particular reason you're looking for it? Or is it just out of interest?

Comment: @Walt - I'm personally intrigued. I've found references to the other artworks in his office on [this site](http://www.anthonywhite.net/wall_street_art.htm), but no reference to the ugly skulls painting.

Comment: The script mentions a [Jean Michel Basquiat](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Jean+Michel+Basquiat+faces&espv=2&biw=1360&bih=643&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi2j8LY2aLJAhVCJw8KHT4GB5MQ_AUIBigB#q=%22Jean+Michel+Basquiat%22+AND+painting&tbm=isch&tbs=ic:specific,isc:blue) skull, but that's visible slightly later in the scene.

Comment: @Richard yeah that site is nice but it didn't have the info, neither image search helped. And I really like this 'ugly' painting :)

Comment: While this could be taken as someone wanting to know for mere trivia purposes, sometimes things like this can actually have hidden meaning intended by the director/set designer/writer, et al.

Comment: @MattD Which the questions unfortunately doesn't ask for at all, though.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's a painting by Greek-American artist [Lucas Samaras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_Samaras) titled *The Collectors* from 1985, oil on canvas. He's one of the artists in the end credits and you can find the painting in several websites like [this one](http://www.mutualart.com/Artwork/THE-COLLECTORS/00F876386BE1ED56) and [this one](http://www.invaluable.com/auction-lot/lucas-samaras-596-c-lzcp0z5yqi).

[image]

Comment: Interesting. It appears that they're individual panels rather than a continuous painting.

Comment: What I wonder most is whether they'd use the originals or a reproduction... But that's another question altogether!